# Retrieving serialize data in a PHP file called using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Form sending AJAX code:

```
var str = $("form").serialize();
alert(str);
// var uns=@unserialize(str);
//alert(uns);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update.php",
    data: "box1="+str,
    success: function(value)
    {
        $("#data").html(value);  
    }
```

HTML Form:

```
<form>
  <input type=checkbox name=box[] value='1'/><input type=checkbox name=box[] value='2'/>
</form>
```

In my PHP:

```
$box=$_POST['box1'];
```

How can I access each of the box variable values in PHP side?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your js should be like this:

```
var str = $("form").serializeArray();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "update.php",  
    data: str,  
    success: function(value) {  
            $("#data").html(value);
    }
});
```

With php you should loop your result array.

```
$box = $_POST['box'];
foreach ($box as $x) {
    echo $x;
}
```

**Edit:**
You have to use serializeArray function in jQuery. Then it will work with this code.

Comment: i made the changes what you suggest me, but it giving me the following error message:    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Answer (score 9):

Provided that your server is receiving a string that looks something like this

```
    $("form").serialize();
   "param1=someVal&param2=someOtherVal"
```

...something like this is probably all you need:

```
    $params = array();
    parse_str($_GET, $params);
```

$params should then be an array modeled how you would expect. Note this works also with HTML arrays.

See the following for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Hope that's helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

your JS should be like this -

```
var str = $( "form" ).serializeArray();
    var postData = new FormData();
     $.each(str, function(i, val) {
                postData.append(val.name, val.value);
 });
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: postData,
           url: action,
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(data){
              alert(data);
          }
    });
```

Now do this in your php script -

```
print_r($_POST);
```

you will get all form data in alert box.

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = array();
foreach(explode('&', $_POST[data]) as $value)
{
    $value1 = explode('=', $value);
    $data[$value1[0]] = validateInput($value1[1]);
}

var_dump($data['box']);
```

Comment: some explanation of solution would help all.

Answer (score 2):

your data in php will contain a string like this

`field1=value1&field2=value2&....`

so you can get your value1 using `$_POST['field1]` , value2 with `$_POST['field2']`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
data: "box1="+str,
```

into

```
data: str,
```

`serialize()` will produce a string like: `input1=value1&input2=value2`. So in your php you can access each value with, for instance `$value1 = $_PHP['input1'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
values=$("#edituser_form").serialize();//alert(values);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/ajax_call.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: values,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

$box=$_POST['box'];
and $box is an array.

Comment: $_POST is an array, too, so your answer is redundant. I'm left wondering what you intend to do with `$box`? Are you implying something?