# How to send an array to php with jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to create an array with serializeArray and post it to php. but my code doesn't work. I read this questions ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430918/retrieving-serialize-data-in-a-php-file-called-using-ajax)) but I didn't understand my mistake yet.

this is my ajax code

```
    var str = $("form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myfile.php",
        data: str,
        success: function (value) {
            $("#mydata").html(value);
        }
    });
```

HTML Code

```
<form>
    <select name="num0">
        <option value="">num0</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>
    <select name="num1">
        <option value="">num2</option>
        <option value="123">123</option>
        <option value="133">133</option>
    </select>
    <select name="num2">
        <option value="">num3</option>      
        <option value="12345">12345</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
$postarr = array();
$num=$_POST['num0'];
$postarr[]=$num;
$num=$_POST['num1'];
$postarr[]=$num;
$num=$_POST['num2'];
$postarr[]=$num;
```

it giving me the following error message:

**Notice**: Undefined index: num0 (and same message for other variables).

By the way, English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: I don't know if this is related or not, but your  `<form>` tag needs a method.  Since it isn't proper HTML, the serialize may not work.

Comment: use `$("form").serialize()`, not `$("form").serializeArray();` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10430571/689579

Comment: Did you try to debug with `print_r($_REQUEST);` ?

Comment: @SableFoste: `method` and `action` are optional.  By default, the form will submit to the current page via GET.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XN6aJ/ (Check the headers of the request)

Comment: Thanks @Rocket , is there any way to send the value without button? I read something about .change on jquery, but I don't know how to use it on this problem. because I have 3 select

Comment: @user1967994: You could bind the `.change` event then send the request once all 3 selects have a set value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myfile.php",
     data: $('form').serialize(),
     success: function (value) {
         $("#mydata").html(value);
     }
 });
```

and instead of

```
$num=$_POST['num0']
```

use

```
$num=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'num0');
```

Comment: Thanks @andrew, but when I tried to echo $num, it doesn't echo $num value.

Answer (score 0):

With the name attribute of an input field you are able to create an array in your `$_POST`:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="values[num0]">
        <option value="">num0</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>
    <select name="values[num1]">
        <option value="">num2</option>
        <option value="123">123</option>
        <option value="133">133</option>
    </select>
    <select name="values[num2]">
        <option value="">num3</option>      
        <option value="12345">12345</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In your php you can use it like this:

```
$postarr = $_POST['values'];
echo $postarr['num0'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Dinistro ,but it giving me this error: values are undefined

Comment: @ArvinFirouzi did you also copy my html? By me, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your form,

```
  <form id="my_form">
<select name="num0">
    <option value="">num0</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<select name="num1">
    <option value="">num2</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="133">133</option>
</select>
<select name="num2">
    <option value="">num3</option>      
    <option value="12345">12345</option>
</select>
```

Just change

```
  var str = $("#my_form").serialize();
```

In your script